# Query related to disk encryption in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

If I have chosen full disk encryption or home encryption in ubuntu, can anyone boot my system using live usb and assess the data in encrypted folder ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Not with out the key, or some kind of exploit to the encryption implementation. The whole point of encryption of the whole disk or individual folders is to prevent access.